# Update only existing fields when source has content

Tags: migrations

When migrating into a pre-existing node, I know that I can specify which fields to update using the `overwrite_properties`. It looks like if the destination field is included in `overwrite_properties` and it already has content, that content will be removed, whether the source has any content for that field or not.

I had assumed that if I used the `skip_on_empty` plugin when importing (with `method: process` since I still want to migrate the other fields), it wouldn't change the destination field if the source is empty, but it looks like regardless of whether the source field is empty or not, all fields in the `overwrite_properties` array will automatically be cleared out.

What I would like to do is preserve the preexisting content in that field by default and only overwrite it if the source has content for that field.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can load entity exited on method **prepareRow()** and mapping some fields with source. Then you can set field have value for empty source. This way can resolve your problem. But I don't like it.